# How can I save a <template> for a second use?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-template

I'm trying to properly use HTML5 templates in a webpage. However, I discovered that when I take the content of a template and put it into some section of the webpage, the template is emptied and the same action can't be performed again. **How do I ensure the template isn't emptied, or should I be using a different technique?**

### Example

HTML:

```
<div>
    <button id="replace-button">Click to show template</button>
    <div id="holder"></div>
</div>

<template id="my-template">Hooray! Now, note that when you try again, this area will be blank.</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#replace-button").click(replaceWithTemplate);

function replaceWithTemplate(event) {
    $("#holder").html($("#my-template")[0].content);
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Supuhstar/y33a9/

Comment: Side note: did you mean to tag jQuery instead of/with JavaScript?

Comment: @CaseyFalk good point! I did not tag JQ because this does not depend on JQ. I used it for code compression, but could have just as easily used `addEventListener`, `document.getElementById`, etc. in naked JS and the question and its underlying problem would remain the same, as far as I know.

Comment: Okeydoke. Just clarifying.

Comment: use $("#my-template")[0].cloneNode(true).content

Comment: Interesting. @dandavis, why must we clone the entire node if we only access the `content`?

Comment: Especially since the docs say the `content` attribute is "read-only" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Comment: the content is the entire node; the content goes live when put into a tree.

Comment: Okay, and you can't access the `content` of a live template? So instead, we're cloning it so that the template never goes live but we can read it anyway? Huh. What is the benefit of effectively disabling a template? I wonder why they made that design choice...

Comment: @dandavis, do you want to write that as an answer or shall I? It probably should be mentioned somewhere that isn't a comment.

Comment: @CaseyFalk:  the design choice with <template> was made to keep <img> tags from loading, among other things. good answer.essentially, it's just a semantic way to put a semi-arbitrary string in html, with some sugar to easily create a fragment from that string.

Comment: Oh, nifty. I hadn't even thought about delaying resource requests. Very cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"How do I ensure the template isn't emptied?"*

After you use the `content` of the template, the template becomes "live" (as [Eric terms it](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/)). **You can't read the `content` of a "live" template.** Thus, if you want to reuse a template, you should *clone* the template's `content` and never activate the original template in the first place.

---

**jQuery**

As [Will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3027317/will) mentioned, you can use jQuery's `.clone()` method to accomplish this. You could also use the `.html()` method with the same results. **[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/y33a9/2/)**

**Pure JavaScript**

As [Dan Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis) mentioned in a comment, you can also use the `.cloneNode(true)` method of the template `node` to perform a deep copy of the template. Thus, you don't activate the original template, you active the clone. **[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/y33a9/3/)**

**Alternatively,** the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) use `.importNode()` to copy template `content`.

Comment: Is there any way to make a template no longer live?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't "kill" a template and make it "live" again later. Making a template "live" is a one-way street. That being said, if you just always *copy* the template, you shouldn't have any problems. : )

Answer (score 2):

Simply add **clone()** , then you can use it again.

```
$("#replace-button").click(function(event) {
    $("#holder").html($("#my-template").clone()[0].content);
});
```

Comment: `.html()` seems to work as well, instead of `.clone()[0].content`. (http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/y33a9/2/)

Comment: @CaseyFalk that does work, but is it the way the W3C intended? I'd use it if I weren't so worried about the proper way to do things

Comment: "is it the way the W3C intended?" -- I don't think the W3C intended you to use jQuery. ;) The difference between `.clone()` and `.html()` is a jQuery question.

Comment: @CaseyFalk again, this does not depend on JQ. I used it for code compression, but could have just as easily used addEventListener, document.getElementById, etc. in naked JS and the question and its underlying problem would remain the same, as far as I know.

Comment: @CaseyFalk I more meant "Did the W3C intend for the contents of a template to be cloned before read?"

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha! I haven't found anything to back this up (see my answer), but I would say that they envisioned templates as being "activated" and then staying activated in a one-time-use sort of way (since they went to the effort of letting them render at all). Obviously copying the content isn't *bad* practice, but it is *different*. :)